# How to update java project properties with gradle commandline

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, properties-file, system-properties

I'm working on a java project and currently loading properties by:

```
 properties.load(ConfigProperty.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("project.properties"));
```

But sometimes I also need to run from command line and pass values to override the values in project.properties.

I tried something like this(user is a key in properties), but doesn't really work.

```
gradle gatlingRun -Duser=1
```

What should be the proper way to do it?

Is it the way properties.load limiting it to only read from file? Should change this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `getResourceAsStream` method then.  This can't be overridden with system properties as you show in your example.

It's not clear what your overall environment is but systems like Quarkus include a [configuration subsystem](https://quarkus.io/guides/config) to help you do exactly this.  You can use system properties, environment variables, and files.

For smaller command line type applications I've used [Apache Commons configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) that also can read from a variety of places.  It's simple and has a very large number of sources.